# How to convert a nested dictionary with lists to a dataframe in this format

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

What can I do to convert a nested dictionary like this example:

```
nested_dict = { 'Girl': {'June': [45, 32], 'Samantha': [14, 34, 65]},
                'Boy': {'Brad': [12, 54, 12], 'Chad': [12]}}
```

to a dataframe of this format?:

```
Col1      Col2       Col3  
June      Girl       45
June      Girl       32
Samantha  Girl       14
Samantha  Girl       34
Samantha  Girl       65
Brad      Boy        12
Brad      Boy        54
Brad      Boy        12
Chad      Boy        12
```

failed attempt:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(nested_dict, orient='index')

df
Out[17]: 
           June      Samantha          Brad  Chad
Girls  [45, 32]  [14, 34, 65]           NaN   NaN
Boys        NaN           NaN  [12, 54, 12]  [12]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `stack` and `explode`:

```
import pandas as pd

nested_dict = { 'Girl': {'June': [45, 32], 'Samantha': [14, 34, 65]},
                'Boy': {'Brad': [12, 54, 12], 'Chad': [12]}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(nested_dict, orient='index')
print(df.stack().explode())
```

Output:

```
Girl  June        45
      June        32
      Samantha    14
      Samantha    34
      Samantha    65
Boy   Brad        12
      Brad        54
      Brad        12
      Chad        12
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the option `orient="index"` because that converts each dictionary key into a single row, but your original dictionary is more complexly structured.

You have to manually reprocess the dictionary before converting it because the original data you have are normalized - they is nested according to shared data values. The DataFrame object you want to create is explicitly NOT normalized.

Here is some code to de-normalize your data so it can be converted:

```
nested_dict = {
   'Girl': { 'June': [45, 32], 'Samantha': [14, 34, 65] },
   'Boy': { 'Brad': [12, 54, 12], 'Chad': [12] }
}

metaDF = { 'Col1' : [], 'Col2' : [], 'Col3' : [] }

for gender in nested_dict:
   for person in nested_dict[gender]:
      for age in nested_dict[gender][person]:
         metaDF['Col1'].append( person )
         metaDF['Col2'].append( gender )
         metaDF['Col3'].append( age )

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict( metaDF, orient="columns" )
```

Reference:

- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html
- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html#pandas.DataFrame.from_dict

Answer (score 0):

By using Stack () and explode () function, you can achieve your expected outcome.

```
nested_dict = { 'Girl': {'June': [45, 32], 'Samantha': [14, 34, 65]},
                    'Boy': {'Brad': [12, 54, 12], 'Chad': [12]}}
    
    
mydict = pd.DataFrame(nested_dict).stack().reset_index()
mydict = mydict.set_axis(['A', 'B', 'C'], axis='columns').explode ('C')
print (mydict)

          A     B   C
0      June  Girl  45
0      June  Girl  32
1  Samantha  Girl  14
1  Samantha  Girl  34
1  Samantha  Girl  65
2      Brad   Boy  12
2      Brad   Boy  54
2      Brad   Boy  12
3      Chad   Boy  12
```